# Using structs in oneOf field in Protocol Buffers v3 via Go

Tags: json, go, protocol-buffers, grpc

So trying to using Protocol Buffers v3 and Go together (new to both).

**example.proto**

```
syntax = "proto3";

package test;

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

message Metadata {
    uint64 userID = 2;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp time= 3; 
}

//SignOff when user logs out of Glory
message SignOff {
    Metadata metadata =1;
}

//SignOn when user logs into Glory
message SignOn {
    Metadata metadata =1;
}

message EventWrapper {
    oneof event {
        SignOff signOff = 1;
        SignOn signOn = 2;
    }
}
```

Converting with `protoc` and using in Go

```
now, _ := ptypes.TimestampProto(time.Now())
event := &pb_test.EventWrapper{
    Event: &pb_test.EventWrapper_SignOn{
        SignOn: &pb_test.SignOn{
            Metadata: &pb_test.Metadata{
                UserID: 1234,
                Time:   now,
            },
        },
    },
}
protoBytes, err := proto.Marshal(event)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
log.Println(len(protoBytes) == 0)

jsonBytes, _ = json.MarshalIndent(event, "", "\t")
log.Println(string(jsonBytes))
```

The output shows the JSON is right but the protobuf encoded byte array is empty.

```
{
    "Event": {
        "SignOn": {
            "metadata": {
                "userID": 1234,
                "time": {
                    "seconds": 1491143507,
                    "nanos": 654053400
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The intent is the have a array of these (`repeated *EventWrapper`) to send along the wire via gRPC, but the individual ones don't work at the moment.  The protobuf [Language Guide](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#oneof) doesn't say anything about structs not being allowed.  Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing in the Protocol Buffer documentation indicates `oneof` cannot be structs, and in fact the [example](https://github.com/gogo/protobuf) generates structs for a `union` field.

I recommend using [gogo](https://github.com/gogo/protobuf), which I have personally used for previous commercial projects. Specifically, `use protoc-gen-gogoslick`

See [this section](https://github.com/gogo/protobuf#more-speed-and-more-generated-code) for installing the necessary packages, then run the following for your project

```
protoc --gogoslick_out=Mgoogle/protobuf/timestamp.proto=github.com/gogo/protobuf/types:. example.proto
```